# How to calculate average color of a superpixel in scikit-image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image, superpixels

I have segmented my image using the quickshift method found in the scikit image libary. How can I calculate the average color and the area of a superpixel? How can I interpret the return value of the quickshift() method? The documentation says the return value is "Integer mask indicating segment labels" but this is not clear for me. How can I make a boolean array in the shape of the original image, filled with ones, where the particular superpixel is present, in this presentation my life would be easier(I used to work with this kind of masks in OpenCV). Can you help me with this? My code (simplified example from scikit-image website):

```
from skimage.data import astronaut
from skimage.segmentation import felzenszwalb, slic, quickshift
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries
from skimage.util import img_as_float

img = img_as_float(astronaut()[::2, ::2])
segments_quick = quickshift(img, kernel_size=3, max_dist=6, ratio=0.5)

print("Quickshift number of segments: %d" % len(np.unique(segments_quick)))
plt.imshow(mark_boundaries(img, segments_quick))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `skimage.measure.regionprops` function returns the properties of labeled regions, including the ones you are interested in: average and area.  You use it as follows:

```
from skimage import measure
regions = measure.regionprops(segments_quick, intensity_image=img)
```

`regions` is a list, with each entry a RegionProperty object representing a superpixel.  You can query the region properties as follows:

```
print([r.area for r in regions])
print([r.mean_intensity for r in regions])
```

Comment: How can I get mean intensity values for a rgb image for each channel?

Comment: If you run the above code, it will give you exactly that.

Comment: It gives combined mean intensity. But I need it separately for each channel.

Comment: ```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure, data

cat = data.chelsea()
labels = np.zeros_like(cat[..., 0], dtype=int)
labels[:100] = 1
labels[100:] = 2

regions = measure.regionprops(labels, intensity_image=cat)

print(regions[0].mean_intensity)
```

```
[142.23179601 106.63430155  83.25536585]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple, straight forward and generic code to represnt each pixel with the mean of its superpixel.

Here the label array is obtained using SLIC, any other approach can be used to generate the labels.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from skimage import segmentation
from skimage.data import astronaut

img=cv2.cvtColor(astronaut(),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

[image]

```
label=segmentation.slic(img,compactness=10, n_segments=1000)

def mean_image(image,label):

im_rp=image.reshape((image.shape[0]*image.shape[1],image.shape[2]))
sli_1d=np.reshape(label,-1)    
uni=np.unique(sli_1d)
uu=np.zeros(im_rp.shape)
for i in uni:
    loc=np.where(sli_1d==i)[0]
    #print(loc)
    mm=np.mean(im_rp[loc,:],axis=0)
    uu[loc,:]=mm
oo=np.reshape(uu,[image.shape[0],image.shape[1],image.shape[2]]).astype('uint8')
cv2.imshow('img',oo)
```

---

```
output=mean_image(img,label) # displays the output image.
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `label2rgb` can also be used for this purpose: https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.15.x/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.label2rgb

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt but label2rgb outputs false color output, however above code outputs true color segments.

Comment: Not with the `kind='avg'` flag.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me was this:

```
from skimage import segmentation, color
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.future import graph
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = imread('test.jpeg')

img_segments = segmentation.slic(img, compactness=20, n_segments=500)
superpixels = color.label2rgb(img_segments, img, kind='avg')
```